# Magento new checkout and payment module

Tags: module, payment, checkout, magento

We're attempting to write a Magento module integrating with a new payment method and checkout process.

This will be very similar to the Paypal Express Checkout process. We've found that Paypal Express Checkout is part of core - it's not a module.

My question is what is the best approach to this?

1. Should we extend `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart.php` and overload `getMethods`,
2. or should we use observers to catch that we're on the page `index.php/checkout/cart/`, fetch the block and add our required elements to it?

What would be the proper approach to writing this kind of module?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding any framework libraries is never a good thing (unless you've ran into a bug an need a quick patch). From a maintainability perspective this is a nightmare, and you will not be able to share your code that easily.

That said, you might be better off writing your own custom payment method. The internet provides many tutorial among this one: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method Moreover, Magento is very modular in nature and has it's own marketplace (if you feel the need for others to use your payment method).

PS. When building your payment method there is no need to work with Magento observers or overwrite any implementations (only the abstract handles), it all happens within the workflow of the checkout.